# Keep checkbox values on content update

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been struggling with this issue for a while now. Maybe you can help.

I have a table with a checkbox at the beginning of each row. I defined a function which reloads the table at regular intervals. It uses jQuery's load() function on a JSP which generates the new table.

The problem is that I need to preserve the checkbox values until the user makes up his mind on which items to select. Currently, their values are lost between updates.

The current code I use that tries to fix it is:

```
 refreshId = setInterval(function()
 {
        var allTicks = new Array();
        $('#myTable input:checked').each(function() {
            allTicks.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        $('#myTable').load('/get-table.jsp', null,
                function (responseText,textStatus, req ){
            $('#my-table').tablesorter();
            //alert(allTicks + ' length ' + allTicks.length);
            for (i = 0 ; i < allTicks.length; i++ )
                $("#my-table input#" + allTicks[i]).attr('checked', true);

        });
}, $refreshInterval);
```

The id of each checkbox is the same as the table entry next to it.

My idea was to store all the checked checkboxes' ids into an array before the update and to change their values after the update is done, as most of the entries will be preserved, and the ones that are new won't really matter.

'#myTable' is the div in which the table is loaded and '#my-table' is the id of the table which is generated. The checkbox inputs are generated along with the new table and with the same ids as before.

The weird thing is that applying tablesorter to the newly generated table works, but getting the elements with the stored ids doesn't.

Any solutions?

P.S: I know that this approach to table generation isn't really the best, but my JS skills were limited back then. I'd like to keep this solution for now and fix the problem.

**EDIT:**

Applied the syntax suggested by Didier G. and added some extra test blocks that check the status before and after the checkbox ticking.

Looks like this now:

```
refreshId = setInterval(function()
    {
        var allTicks = []
        var $myTable = $('#my-table');
        allTicks = $myTable.find('input:checked').map(function() { return this.id; });

        $('#myTable').load('/get-table.jsp', null,
        function (responseText,textStatus, req ){
            $myTable = $('#my-table');
            $('#my-table').tablesorter();
            var msg = 'Before: \n';
            $myTable.find('input').each(function(){
                msg = msg + this.id + " " + $(this).prop('checked') + '\n';
            });
            //alert(msg);
            //alert(allTicks + ' length ' + allTicks.length);
            for (i = 0 ; i < allTicks.length; i++ ){
                 $myTable.find('#' + allTicks[i]).prop('checked', true);
            }
            msg = 'After: '
            $myTable.find('input').each(function(){
                msg = msg + this.id + " " + $(this).prop('checked') + '\n';
            });
            //alert(msg);
        });
    }, $refreshInterval);
```

If I uncomment the alert lines, and check 2 checkboxes, on the next update I get (for 3 row table):

```
Before: host2 false
host3 false
host4 false

object [Object] length 2

After: host2 false
host3 false
host4 false
```

Also did a previous check on the contents of the array and it has all the correct entries.

Can the DOM change or working with an entirely new table instance be a cause of this?

**EDIT2:**

Here's a sample of the table generated by the JSP (edited for confidentiality purposes):

```
<table id="my-table" class="tablesorter">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Full Name</th> 
        <th>IP Address</th> 
        <th>Role</th> 
        <th>Job Slots</th> 
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Management</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>head</td>
        <td>10.20.1.14</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>ON</td>
        <td>Permanent</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="host2" name="host2"/>
            host2
        </td>
        <td>10.20.1.7</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>BSTART</td>
        <td>Dynamic</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="host3" name="host3"/>
        host3</td>
        <td>10.20.1.9</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>BSTART</td>
        <td>Dynamic</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" id="host4" name="host4"/>
        host4</td>
        <td>10.20.1.11</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>BSTART</td>
        <td>Dynamic</td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Note that the id and name of the checkbox coincide with the host name. Also note that the first td does not have a checkbox. That's the expected behavior.

Comment: Haven't you forgotten a #: `$("#my-table input#"...`?

Comment: the # is there, but I accidentally erased it when renaming the table id in this post :) edited out

Comment: TableSorter plugin does not seem to change the html structure of the table. Could you post the HTML of your table ?

Comment: See edit. Note that the entire table is generated each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of painful hours of digging up every small detail, I realized that my problem was not how I coded the thing, nor was it stuff like unexpected DOM changes, but a simple detail I failed to see:

**The id I was trying to assign to the checkbox contained a period (".") character.**

This causes lots of problems for jQuery when trying to look up that sort of id, because a period as-is acts as a class descriptor. To avoid this, the period character must be escaped using 2 backslashes.

For example:

```
$("#my.id")    // incorrect
$("#my\\.id")  // correct
```

So then the fix in my case would be:

```
$myTable.find('#' + allTicks[i].replace(".", "\\.")).prop('checked', true);
```

... and it finally works.

Thanks everyone for all your helping hands!

Answer (score 2):

Changing 'special' attributes like `disbaled` or `checked` should be done like this:

```
$(...).attr('checked','checked');
```

or this way if you are using jQuery 1.6 or later:

```
$(...).prop('checked', true);  // more reliable
```

See jQUery doc about [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Here's your piece of code modified with a few optimizations (check the comments):

```
refreshId = setInterval(function()
{
    var allTicks = [],
        $myTable = $('#myTable');  // select once and re-use

    // .map() returns an array which is what you are after
    // also never do this: $(this).attr('id').
    // 'id' is a property available in javascript and
    // in .map() (and in .each()), 'this' is the current DOMElement so simply do:
    // this.id

    allTicks = $myTable.find('input:checked').map(function() { return this.id; });

    $myTable.load('/get-table.jsp', null, function (responseText,textStatus, req ) {

        $myTable.tablesorter();

        //alert(allTicks + ' length ' + allTicks.length);
        for (i = 0 ; i < allTicks.length; i++ )
            // avoid prefixing with tagname if you have the ID: input#theId
            // #xxx is unique and jquery will use javascript getElementById which is super fast ;-)
            $myTable.find('#' + allTicks[i]).prop('checked', true);

    });

}, $refreshInterval);
```

Comment: Thanks for the syntax tips. I applied them, but still no luck. See the comment on Eggen's solution for another possible cause.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that the JavaScript *does* retrieve and set the checkboxes ticks.
Then there still is a problem with the asynchrone Ajax call.
First try it with a very large $refreshInterval.

Place the for-loop before the tablesorter call.

Do not setInterval, but setTimeout and schedule this for one single time.
Then in the load function schedule the next time.
This prevents overlapping calls which were a possible cause for the error.

But may stop refreshing, when the load is not called. (Not so important.)

Comment: As far as I can tell using Firebug, there are no overlapping calls. I put up some filters that check the new table's status before and after the so called checkbox ticking. Javascript sees all the new checkboxes from the table, but for some reason fails to tick the ones having the ids from the array. Could it have something to do with the DOM change and working with an entirely new table instance?

Comment: Well, you don't seem to bind any event on the checkboxes, which would dissapear, as well as any other jQuery data after the load(). Are the IDs still the same ? Have you tried surrounding your table with a <div> and use your jQuery from the it instead of directly the table ?

Comment: If you read carefully, then that's how I did it. The div #myTable surrounds the table #my-table. The newly generated ids are the same as the old ones, mainly because they're generated from the same data.

Comment: It's really strange that it doesn't check the boxes. This puzzled me before a few months ago, but I ran short on time and did a workaround by adding a refresh toggle to clear the timeout. Now I need it in another place and it's kind of mandatory I do it this way.